# Как передать элемент в лямбда

Tags: c#, функции, классы, лямбда-выражение

Собственно есть код:

```
TestClass classTT;
Checker.Check((classTT) =>
{
    classTT = GetTestClass();
    // Некий код
    // ..
    return classTT.Displayed;
});

classTT.InitValue(32);
// ...
classTT.SaveToFile('testLog');
```

При компиляции ошибка:

> Delegate 'Func' doesn't take 1 arguments

Как правильно передать `classTT` в лямбда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Его не надо передавать, он туда попадёт автозахватом сам. Все что нужно, это успокоить компилятор, чтобы не выдавал ошибку "не присвоено значение".

```cs
TestClass classTT = null;
Checker.Check(() =>
{
    classTT = GetTestClass();
    // Некий код
    // ..
    return classTT.Displayed;
});

classTT.InitValue(32);
// ...
classTT.SaveToFile('testLog');
```

Но вообще такие штуки надо через возвращаемое значение делать. Старайтесь пробрасывать данные через аргументы и возвращаемые значения, так код будет более гибкий и безопасный.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. А как через возвращаемое значение сделать?

Comment: @SlimRG ну вы же знаете как сделать, чтобы метод что-то вернул.